# Can I actually buy a copy-paste keyboard like the Stack Overflow April Fool's "The Key"?

Tags: discussion, april-fools

So I saw the Stack Overflow April fool joke for ["The Key"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/) and I know it's just a joke. But I kind of want a real one similar to it just for novelty. Are there any products out there actually for sale that act just like it?

Comment: @Machavity Why was this unfeatured?

Comment: @gparyani It had been up a week and they're sold out for now. Plus we're heading into an election.

Answer (score 102):

Back in the spring of 2021, a group of Stackers began dreaming up our [annual April Fool’s joke](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/). We knew that there are memes all over the internet about the copy/paste nature of Stack Overflow and the whole network, and we wanted to have some fun with it - and maybe get some interesting data at the same time.

So every time someone entered the keyboard command to copy characters from Stack Overflow, we showed them a pop-up warning them they were almost out of free copies. If they wanted unlimited access to copy and paste from Stack Overflow, all they needed to do was purchase The Key. We even had a cool prototype built. We failed to anticipate that people would, you know, want to buy the thing.

Never let it be said that we don’t recognize a good idea when we see one.

For the past several months we’ve been working with [Drop](https://drop.com/), a startup specializing in custom keyboards, to make this possible.

There’s a lot more detail over on [the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/?p=18829), but the short summary is: [buy it from Drop](https://drop.com/buy/stack-overflow-the-key-macropad) ($29), do some good through [digitalundivided](https://www.digitalundivided.com/) (it didn’t feel right for Stack Overflow to profit from a meme born of our community, so we’re donating our profits), and feel good about yourself, while getting a cool collector’s item.

**UPDATE:** The initial batch of 2000 keyboards is now sold out but you can preorder one if you missed it - they're estimated to be delivered in December.

Comment: How many of these are being produced?

Comment: Do you accept unicoins as payment?

Comment: Considering there's only three keys on that keyboard, $29 feels pretty expensive, a regular keyboard with ~110 keys costs only $10.

Comment: @Teemu However you don't get a SO key on a regular keyboard :)

Comment: @Teemu Where you do get a keyboard with cherry keys for just 10USD?

Comment: @Scratte Answering that would be spam. Actually 10 €, but with less "cherry keys". I'd recall my current keyboard costed 12 €, I'm not aware of pricing in US, but in my home country keyboards seem to be cheap.

Comment: It's hard to believe no one's started complaining about the fun yet

Comment: @Don'tPanic They did.. but you need to be a moderator to see it :)

Comment: @Teemu you pay for the customization, it's not out of greed.

Comment: @gparyani turns out that only 2000. Pretty amazing they didn't think to make it at least ten times more, now thousands of people will wait for months, for no good reason. Unlike milk, or any food, keyboard doesn't have expiry date. They could easily produce 20k units, and worst case if less than 20k people will order, store them somewhere. Oh well.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 There's no way that we could have known how many would be sold. It's a joke that went over well... but that was 5 months ago, so people could have felt it a bit stale. There's also limitations on how quickly they can be produced. They've increased the pre-order batch from 3k to 5k and that's all they can make by that date. It's possible that if the order had been for 20k, they wouldn't have been ready for months. If we only ever sell 8k, that'd have been 12k surplus - seems like bad business.

Comment: Maybe selling merchandise instead experimenting with collectives/jobs/whatever would be the better business model for SO :)

Comment: I bet branded unicorn plushies would sell like mad :)

Comment: @OlegValter Users already asked for them https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216179/where-can-i-get-a-unicorn :)

Comment: An SO waffle maker would be nice

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, I was thinking about this exact plushy :) My initial thought was about CM/mod plushies but then it dawned on me that we shouldn't promote voodoo practices.

Comment: @OlegValter https://images.bonanzastatic.com/afu/images/b7a4/72fd/bdc2_7729185281/Build_A_Bear_WHITE_TERRIER_Scottie_Westie_RED_COLLAR_Plush_Stuffed_DOG_Puppy_Toy__1_.JPG -- all that's missing is a mod hat

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz well, there already exists at least one [mod plushy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUvZZ.png) :)

Comment: @OlegValter Ohhh

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3  they appear to be roughly 8cm x 4cm x 4cm.  In addition to the manufacturing (and disposal for those unsold) expense, the "somewhere" that 20,000 would have to be stored, excluding shelving, boxes, etc. would be on the order of 80cm x 80cm x 200cm = 0.8m x 0.8m x 2m.  Have you a spare closet?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Too much whimsy.

Comment: I feel betrayed - no bird chirps!

Comment: @CherryDT - Sorry to miss the mark for you.  I suspect you'll adapt though. :-)

Comment: *"We failed to anticipate that people would, you know, want to buy the thing."* Are you sure? *"UPDATE: There has been a lot of interest in purchasing a real life version of our prank. The good news is we anticipated this might happen[...]"* (The Key linked in OP) ;)

Answer (score 18):

Well - I'm aware that there are three-key macro keyboards (and 2-8 key variants) available via [AliExpress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AliExpress) or [eBay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBay). They are programmable - so you can get it to replicate the intended behaviour.

"3 key macro", or "OSU keypad" are suitable search parameters.

For folks of a more DIY bent there's a 3D printable version [here](https://bikerglen.com/blog/presenting-the-single-esc-key-usb-keyboard/) and <strike>I distinctly remember seeing an official 3D printable one that I can't seem to find</strike> and one by one of the [SE developers](https://github.com/b-kelly/stack-overflow-keyboard) here which uses the excellent [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/hardware_avr) firmware.

I have no idea what the key profile is - it's *very* nice and retro - and there are services that print custom keycaps around. I'm guessing they are SA profile from looking around - though I'm uncertain to *who* would print these.

From what I understand Stack had this specific one custom made - so I do wonder if they might be nice enough to let us in on who made it.

---

There was an update to the [original blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/) that says

> UPDATE: There has been a lot of interest in purchasing a real life version of our prank. The good news is we anticipated this might happen and we’ve been working on something along these lines. Stay tuned for more!

So this might be a thing ;)

---

There's a [pre-order up for these things on drop](https://drop.com/buy/stack-overflow-the-key-macropad) if you need your own

Comment: This is the 3D one that Ben Kelly designed. https://github.com/b-kelly/stack-overflow-keyboard

Comment: [The usual suspect indicates it is a thing](https://buttondown.email/cassidoo/archive/to-understand-is-to-invent-jean-piaget/) (why go to all this trouble just for a picture?) - *"...around a month ago asking if we could make a real mechanical keyboard for their prank. It was a mad rush to make it happen! I helped get Drop onboard (heh, keyboard pun), and after designing the caps and case for the board, they* ***got it manufactured***! *I got the sample for it last weekend, did all the product photography on Monday, made the promo video on Wednesday, and got it shipped Thursday!"*

Comment: eh, I kinda was looking at drop to see if they made 3 key macro keyboards and to work out what sort of keys they were. Didn't have much luck, They're good folks (though apparently I have poor luck with them) and if there's an offiicial one, I might pick one up for the lulz .  The usual suspect isn't in my usual orbit of people I follow on the internet so i guess I missed that. That or it was *really* Keyzer Soze

Comment: That’s not such a silly idea. I have an old iMac which I use in the background but keep in Target Display mode. However, every time I restart, I need to set the iMac again, so I have a keyboard attached just to press two or three keys.

Answer (score 12):

I ordered one of the initial 2,000 keyboards, and I've just received mine today.

Here are some shots of the box it came in:

[image: Top of box]

[image: Bottom of box]

[image: Side of box]

Opening the box:

[image: Box open]

Here's a close-up shot at the cable. It's wound like a telephone handset cord so it's long but not unwieldy. The keyboard itself uses a USB-C interface, and the opposite side of the cable is a standard USB-A interface:

[image: Keyboard cable]

...and for the moment you've been waiting for, the actual keyboard itself:

[image: Control key on the left, C in the middle, V on the right]

In case you're wondering, it has mechanical switches for the keys, which are Kailh Black linear switches.

The underside of the keyboard; notice the dints for rubber feet:

[image: Bottom of keyboard]

Also included in the box are some spare screws for the bottom case, and rubber feet to place in the dints:

[image: Bags with screws and rubber feet]

---

Some feedback regarding the product, which I hope will be incorporated into the pre-order models being shipped this December:

- The included cable can only connect the keyboard to computers using a standard USB-A port. It would've been nice if there were a USB-C cable included, so it could be connected to many more devices. It seems strange that a device that's advertised as being "compatible with virtually any [modern] computing device" is incompatible with lots of modern USB-C-only devices, such as many Mac computers made since 2016. It'd be nice if the cable were more like the one which came with my new WD My Passport Ultra external hard drive, which is a USB-C-only cable, with a small adapter at one end to connect it to USB-A ports.
- This may not be an issue for many people, but I find the LED at the back annoying, especially in my particular use case. It'd be nice if there were a way to disable the light through the port at the back of the keyboard. I think there may be a way to do so manually (by opening the bottom cover and removing or covering up the LED), but it'd be nice if there were a way to disable it in the configuration program Drop  (the manufacturer) provides.

Nice to see, for the first time, what was supposed to just be a prank actually become an actual product!

Comment: Where is the LED at the back? What does it light up? The cable and the surface in that direction?

Comment: The LED is just a power indicator, you can see it from underneath and at the power socket, but its not visible at all from your chair. I've been using it a bit, the only thing stopping it from being practical is the missing **A** key. For repetitive use it is actually much more ergonomic, no little finger strain at all!

Comment: @ChrisSchaller It's possible to program it to press two keys at the same time with one key press. You could program it to press the Ctrl key at the same time as pressing the C and V keys, and program the SO key as a Ctrl+A key.

Comment: @gparyani you're a legend mate! Now thats productivity right there... The other common operation is a Ctrl+A and then paste over so that a really elegant solution and appropriate because we all know to grab the entire example from SO, not just the relevant snippet ;) (appropriate the the SO key is select all)